# Расширение для Chrome, работа с DOM

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Ни разу не писал расширение для Хрома. Почитал немного материалы от Гугла. Не сильно помогло, тем более плохо знаю JS.

В общем, что мне нужно. А нужно простое пока действие: открываю сайт, логинюсь, нажимаю на кнопку расширение, активирую его. Расширение периодически по таймеру на этом сайте кликает на Таб в виджете, к которому привязано событие "click", которое дергает ajax запрос и получает данные с сервера и обновляет содержимое Таба. После чего, расширение должно проверить, появилось ли что-то в Табе. Таб - это вкладка в виджете. Если что-то появилось - дергает внешний url.

Как это правильно организовать? Что прописать в манифесте? Как достучаться из расширения к DOM сайта?

В принципе, через devtools кликнутьпо табу могу через: `document.getElementsByClassName('tab')[0].click()`, как это периодически дергать из расширения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы достучатся из расширения к DOM сайта, вам нужен контент скрипт (вся работа с DOM ведется там). В манифесте указываете, в какие страницы его загружать, примерно так: 
**manifest.json**:

```
{
    /*
    тут бла-бла-бла имя автора версия и прочие тырыпыры, 
    https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest тут все достаточно подробно описано
    */
    "permissions":
    [
        "http://ваш.сайт.цель/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://ваш.сайт.цель/*" //https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match-patterns-globs
            ],
            "js": ["content_script.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Чтобы активировать расширение, нажав на кнопку расширение, вам нужен popup:
в манифест добавляем

```
"browser_action":{
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
},
```

в теле popup.html напишите код, который будет сохранять куда-либо факт того, что приложение активировано. Тут масса вариантов, насколько я понял вашу задачу, будет достаточно просто посылать сообщение в content_script, примерно так:

**popup.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>Hello Chrome World:)</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('start');
```

**content_script.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,callback){
    if(request=='start'){
        setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementsByClassName('tab')[0].click()
        },228);
    }
});
```

Но вы можете сделать это массой других способов, например воспользовавшись [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) или [background скриптом](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), который будет работать, пока вы не закроете браузер, удалите или не отключите расширение.

Comment: Спасибо. Пошел пробовать. Отпишусь.

Comment: Попробовал, как вы сказали.
Выходит ошибка для popup.html: "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-jIJZ5Xr7KFK7'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
"

Comment: Апнул ответ, надо скрипт вынести из popup.html в отдельный файл

Comment: Получилось. Чуть-чуть по-другому. Главное - понятно стало, куда копать.

Comment: Для того чтобы добавить content_scripts нужна 3 версия манифеста, а для browser_action не выше 2. Как быть?