# Подключение content script в декларативном стиле

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Пытаюсь достучаться из расширения chrome к dom страницы. Для этого создал два js-файла. Один - для расширения, другой - контент-скрипт. Пытаюсь сделать, как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514493/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-chrome-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-dom). Мой manifest.json выглядит так:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Sotis Unlock",
    "description": "Анализатор страницы в sotis",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {"128": "images/mini_logo.png"},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://vedmark.ru/",
                "https://*.ru/*",
            "http://*.ru/*"
            ],
            "css" : [],
            "js": ["js/content_script.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

В matches по сути я пытаюсь охватить все сайты зоны .ru. `content_script.js` -это тот самый скрипт, который должен отрабатывать внутри dom. Мой тестовый popup.html выглядит так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">  
        <title>Sotis</title>

       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


        <style>
            window.onload = function(){


                contextBtn.onclick = function(){
                    alert('i');
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('GetcontextMnu');
                }


                linksBtn.onclick = function(){
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('Turn_links');
                }   

            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <button id="contextBtn">Вернуть контекстное меню</button>
        <button id="linksBtn">Получить адреса</button>

    </body>

</html>
```

И content_script.js, который лежит отдельно в папке /js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request,sender,callback){

        if (request=='GetcontextMnu') GetcontextMnu();
        else if (request == 'Turn_links') Turn_links();
    }
);


function GetcontextMnu(){

    alert(0);

}




function Turn_links() {

    alert(1);

}
```

Событие `onclick` для contextBtn срабатывает. Далее я ожидаю, что внутри content_script сработает вот этот метод:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request,sender,callback){

        if (request=='GetcontextMnu') GetcontextMnu();
        else if (request == 'Turn_links') Turn_links();
    }
);
```

Но ничего не происходит. И во вкладке content scripts пусто [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? content script не подключился или в самом коде ожидании сообщений что-то не то?

Comment: а где "permissions" ???

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, добавить `"permissions": ["activeTab"]`? Добавил. Ничего не поменялось.

Comment: можно попробовать добавить что-то вроде такого `"permissions": ["tabs", "*://*нужный_домен/*"]`. У меня с этими разрешениями все работает. И не забудь перезагружать расширение в браузере при изменениях

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, а в самом коде ошибок нет?

Comment: я бы не мучил себя попытками получить сообщение, а просто прописал бы в `content_script.js` что-то вроде `console.log(123)`, дабы увидеть в консоли, что он вообще подключается.